# Proper number of confirmations in a small testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, confirmations

In a private blockchain with just 4 miners, what should be the proper number of confirmations? 24 is by default, but does it make sense? should it be just 4 (one per miner)?

Comment: PoA (Clique/Aura/IBFT/...) or PoW?

Comment: I am using PoW. But what would be the difference?

Comment: Different users of the network will have different ideas about their risk profiles. Do the users of your private network know and trust each other? Orthogonal to this: you can't "set" the number of confirmations for the network. A particular user of the network can set the number of confirmations that their particular client instance deems sufficient. Different members of the network can set different values for `transactionConfirmationBlocks`.

Comment: If I'm particularly risk-averse, I might make this value higher, and vice versa.

Comment: But in the case of a blockchain like this with 4 miners, is it logic to keep the number of confirmations in 24?

Comment: I understand that 4 nodes will confirm 24 times the same block repeatedly

Comment: "24 confirmations" means that a user/client will wait for 24 more blocks to be mined on top of the block containing their transaction before they consider their transaction to be irreversible/secure. The number of confirmations is the number of further blocks being mined on top of the one you care about. The more confirmations, the less chance a transaction can be reversed.

Comment: If all 4 of your miners/users trust each other, then really each of them could set this number to 0. If they don't trust each other, they will need to work out how likely they think it is that one of the other users could find enough hash power to launch a 51% attack.

Comment: If this is just a testnet and you don't care about all this, set it to 0 for each client.